# Change Frame of UIScrollView Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview

I have a custom UIScrollView in my app. When the user touches the scroll view I want it to enlarge to fill the entire screen.

I have tried using this code, however nothing happens :

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {

NSLog(@"Touch Detected");
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

}
```

Is there a way to dynamically change the size of the view ? Also is it possible to somehow animate the change in size ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct.  Perhaps your view is clipped within a parent view making it seem as though it didn't resize, in which case you should be mindful of the `clipsToBounds` property of the parent view.  Some other considerations (without knowing what makes you think its not working) is the `contentMode` property of your UIScrollView.  Depending on that value, your UIScrollView may not be redrawing itself.  See [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) for details (read `frame` property)

Animate example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<some float value in seconds> animations:^{

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

}];
```

Details on animate: [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) (read `animateWithDuration:animations:` class method).